# Get currentLag() from consumer API

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to use the currentLag() function in kafka-clients APIs 3.2.x to get the lag, but it gives an error

API

```
public OptionalLong currentLag(TopicPartition topicPartition) {
```

```
KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = ConsumerConstructor.getInstance().buildOffsetConsumer("group_check_msg_cnt");
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionsFor = consumer.partitionsFor("test_topic");
        for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : partitionsFor) {
            TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition());
            OptionalLong optionalLong = consumer.currentLag(topicPartition);
            if (optionalLong.isPresent()) {
                long asLong = optionalLong.getAsLong();
                System.out.println( "partition-" + topicPartition.partition() + ", lag: "+asLong);
            }else {
                System.out.println("---");
            }
        }
        consumer.close();
```

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition test_topic-5
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.assignedState(SubscriptionState.java:370)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SubscriptionState.partitionLag(SubscriptionState.java:542)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.currentLag(KafkaConsumer.java:2260)
        at seoclarity.actonia_competitor_summary.ri.test.Test.process8(Test.java:47)
        at seoclarity.actonia_competitor_summary.ri.test.Test.main(Test.java:36)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This function does not to return the correct value.

Comment: Lag is already available as a JMX Metric. Why loop partitions? Also, as the error says, you need to loop over the assignment for the current consumer, not lookup all topic partitions.